# Comparing sorting methods in C

Tags: c, sorting, bubble-sort, insertion-sort, selection-sort

I have to compare these 3 sorting functions (bubble, insertion, and selection), in their worst, best, and the random possible way to sort an array (when talking about the idea of numbers of comparison).

I built and ran the program. The compiler is working, everything seems fine. The problem is that after the cmd window appears, nothing happens. The program is not returning anything (neither 0 (because of return 0) or writing sth in the file). How can I fix it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int b[11000];
int w[11000];
int r[11000];
int n;

int comp;
int attr;

FILE*f;

//CREAREA SIRURILOR
//best, worst, random

void sir(int n)
{ int i;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        b[i] = i;
        r[i] = rand() % n;
        w[i] = n-i-1;

    }
}

//INSERTION SORT
void insertion (int a[1000])
{
    int j, i, index;

    comp = 0;
    attr = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        index = a[i];
        j = i;
        attr+=1;

        while ((j > 0) && (a[j-1] > index))
        { comp++;
            a[j] = a[j-1];
            j = j-1;
            attr+=1;
        }

        while ((j > 0) || (a[j-1] > index))
        { comp++;
        }
        a[j] = index;
        attr++;
    }

    fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", comp);
    fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", attr);
    fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", attr+comp);
}

//Selection Sort
void selection (int a[1000])
{
    int j, i, min, temp;
    comp = 0;
    attr = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
    {
        min = i;
        for (j = i+1; j < n; j++){
            comp++;
            if (a[j] < a[min])
                min = j;
        }
        temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[min];
        a[min] = temp;
        attr+=3;
    }
fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", comp);
fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", attr);
fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", attr+comp);
}


//Bubble Sort
void bubblesort (int array[2000])
{
    int sorted;
    int swap,d;
    int c;

    comp = 0;
    attr = 0;

    for (c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
    {
        for (d = 0; d < n - c - 1; d++)
        {
        comp++;
        if (array[d] > array[d + 1])
        {

            swap = array[d];
            array[d] = array[d + 1];
            array[d + 1] = swap;
            attr += 3;
        }
        }
    }

    fprintf(f,"\t  %d\t", comp);
    fprintf(f,"\t  %d\t", attr);
    fprintf(f,"\t%d\t", attr+comp);
}

void InsertionSort()
{
    insertion(b);
    insertion(r);
    insertion(w);
}

void SelectionSort()
{
    selection(b);
    selection(r);
    selection(w);
}

void BubbleSort()
{
    bubblesort(b);
    bubblesort(r);
    bubblesort(w);
}


int main ()
{

    f = fopen("iesire.txt","w+");
    if(f == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(-1);
    }

    fprintf(f,"\n Bubble Sort\t\n");
    fprintf(f,"\tBest\t\t\t\t\t\tAverage\t\t\t\t\t\tWorst\t\t\n");
    fprintf(f,"\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\t\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\t\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\n");

    for (n = 100; n<=10000; n+=500)
    {

        sir(n);
        BubbleSort();
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }

    fprintf(f,"\n\n Selection Sort\t\n");
    fprintf(f,"\tBest\t\t\t\t\t\tAverage\t\t\t\t\t\tWorst\t\t\n");
    fprintf(f,"\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\t\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\t\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\n");

    for (n = 100; n<=10000; n+=500)
    {
        sir(n);
        InsertionSort();
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }

    fprintf(f,"\n\n Insertion Sort\t\n");
    fprintf(f,"\tBest\t\t\t\t\t\tAverage\t\t\t\t\t\tWorst\t\t\n");
    fprintf(f,"\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\t\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\t\tComparatii\t\tAtribuiri\t\tComp+Atr\n");

    for (n = 100; n<=10000; n+=500)
    {
        sir(n);
        SelectionSort();
        fprintf(f,"\n");
    }

    fclose(f);
    printf(" Result: 'iesire.txt'.");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger. That will tell you immediately what the program is doing and where.

Comment: I suspect your program simply takes a long, long time, as you are running quadratic algorithms on large input (is there perhaps a lesson there?) Try with just `n==100` first; then increase `n` slowly until the running time grows intolerably long.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: `while ((j > 0) || (a[j-1] > index))
        { comp++;
        }` might occurs infinite loop.